# can one airplane be listed in the OPS Specs of 2 different airlines

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations

Can an airplane be listed in the OPS Specs of 2 different airlines? One airline, Atlas also holds the Polar operating certificate.  They are two different operation certificates.  Can one airplane be listed in both Atlas and Polar ops specs?

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!